# How do I parse XML with attribute in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml which has many number of rows. For a particular given attribute id, the element name and price value should be queried. For instance, my tree looks like:

```
<menu>
 <food id="1">
  <name>Pesto Chicken Sandwich</name>
  <price>$7.50</price>
 </food>
 <food id="2">
  <name>Chipotle Chicken Pizza</name>
  <price>$12.00</price>
 </food>
 <food id="3">
  <name>Burrito</name>
  <price>$6.20</price>
 </food>
</menu>
```

How can I get the name and price value of an particular id(1 or 2 or 3)?

I tried minidom for parsing. My code is:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('D:/test.xml')
nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('food')
for node in nodes:
 if node.attributes['id'].value == '1':
     ????????????????????
```

And am unable to retrieve the name and price tag value. I checked lot of examples and none satisfied.

It Worked. Code is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
 testing  = child.get('id')
 if testing == '3':
    print child.tag, child.attrib
    print child.find('name').text
    print child.find('price').text
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: Which bit are you stuck with. Xml or XPath. Show us some code.

Comment: Please find the answer here, if you wanna use xpath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093002/finding-elements-by-attribute-with-lxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the standard [etree library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). It allows you to parse an xml file into a Python object called an ElementTree. You can then call various methods on this object, such as `.findall("./food/name").`

This might get you started:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def get_info(food_id):
    for child in root.findall("*[@id='{0}']//".format(food_id)):
        print(child.text)

get_info(1)
```

output:

```
Pesto Chicken Sandwich
$7.50
```