# Find all elements in ElementTree by attribute using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml, which has a lot of different nodes with the different tags, but the same attribute. Is it possible to find all these nodes?

I know, that it is possible to find all nodes by attribute, if they all have the same tag:

```
root.findall(".//tag[@attrib]")
```

but in my case they all have different tags. Something like this is not working:

```
root.findall(".//[@attrib]")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XPath you can use `*` to reference element of any name, and you can use `@*` to reference attribute of any name :

```
root.findall(".//*[@attrib]")
```

**side notes :**

As a heads up, if you're really using `lxml` (not just accidentally tagged the question with [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml)), I would suggest to use `xpath()` method instead of `findall()`. The former has much better XPath support. For example, when you need to find element of limited set of names, say `foo` and `bar`, you can use the following XPath expression with `xpath()` method :

```
root.xpath("//*[self::foo or self::bar][@attrib]")
```

The same expression above when passed to `findall()` will result in an error :

> SyntaxError: prefix 'self' not found in prefix map